# Calcular distancia entre dos puntos

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

en Sql server 2008 era muy simple para mi obtener la distancia entre dos puntos latitud y longitud, pero ahora estoy ocupando Sql server 2005 y el tipo de dato `geography` al parecer no existe... Yo hacia esto :

```
DECLARE @source geography = 'POINT(0 51.5)'
DECLARE @target geography = 'POINT(-3 56)'

SELECT @source.STDistance(@target)
```

Lamentablemente esto no funciona para mi en Sql server 2005

Alguna idea o tipo de dato que me ayude con esto, si es que no existe tendre que hacer el calculo digamos "manual"?

Comment: "El tipo de datos está disponible desde SQL Server 2008, puede obtener más información aquí:" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx esta en 2008

Comment: oh ... :/ vaya.

Comment: SQL Server 2005 es un dinosaurio. Sería bueno convencer a quien sea de hacerle un upgrade... si no, creo que te va a tocar hacerlo manualmente como dices.

Comment: @sstan lamentablemente no puedo manejar eso :( lo hare manual entonces, saludos!

Comment: @sioesi: Lo siento mucho :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En SQL 2005, no existe el tipo de dato [geography](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx). Si tomas en cuenta la forma real de la tierra, esto se vuelve complicado (además, hay muchos [sistemas de referencia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system) en los que puedes querer interpretar las coordenadas.

Simplificando todo a que la tierra fuera una esfera (que no lo es, y por tanto el resultado si implementas esta respuesta será solo una aproximación de la realidad), podrías hacer algo como esto, ya que al final el cálculo no es más que un poco de trigonometría:

```
create function deg2rad(@deg float) returns float
as
begin
  return @deg * 3.1415926536 / 180;
end
go


create function DistanceFromLatLonInKm (@lon1 float, @lat1 float, @lon2 float, @lat2 float) returns float 
as 
begin
  declare @R float = 6371; --radio de una _tierra_ esférica en Km.
  declare @dLat float = dbo.deg2rad(@lat2 - @lat1);
  declare @dLon float = dbo.deg2rad(@lon2 - @lon1);

  declare @a float;
  set @a = sin(@dLat / 2) * sin(@dLat / 2)
         + cos(dbo.deg2rad(@lat2)) * cos(dbo.deg2rad(@lat2)) * sin(@dlon / 2) * sin(@dlon / 2);

  declare @c float = 2 * atn2(sqrt(@a), sqrt(1-@a));
  declare @d float = @R * @c;
  return @d;
end
go
```

Con estas funciones definidas, obtendrías este resultado:

```
select dbo.DistanceFromLatLonInKm(0, 51.5, -3, 56);

534.04509287162
```

Comment: En realidad todo es una aproximación a la realidad (incluso si realizamos los cálculos sobre un elipsoide, que es lo que se suele hacer). La mejor aproximación es dar las coordenadas en un marco de referencia (materialización de un sistema de referencia) para una época determinada. +1 por la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias!!! me sirvio y tambien gracias por tu explicación tan completa!

Comment: @Jose, buen punto, siempre es una aproximación de la realidad, digamos que unas más cercanas a ella que otras. :)

Comment: @sioesi, un gusto ;)